# No exact matches in call to subscript

Tags: arrays, swift, string, character

I have an array of strings ["apple", "banana", "cabbage"], and I want to get the first letter of a random one and then the next letter after it on another array. That is why I'm looking for the `firstIndex`, to get the letter after it but on `let char = Array(word)[firstIndex]` I get the error:

```
No exact matches in call to subscript
```

I'm trying to get a letter from a `String`, after the index of

```
func randomNumber(array: [String]) -> Int {
    return Int.random(in: 0..<array.count)
}

func randomWord(array: [String]) -> String {
    let randomNumberGenerated = randomNumber(array: array)
    return array[randomNumberGenerated]
}


 func generateRandomWord(array: [String]) -> String {

    var randomNumber = randomNumber(array: array)
    var word = randomWord(array: array)
    var newWord = ""
    if let word = word.first {
        newWord = String(word)
    }

    if let character = newWord.last {
        word = randomWord(array: array)
        let firstIndex = word.firstIndex(of: character)
        let char = Array(word)[firstIndex]
    }
}
```

I'm trying to convert `String` to `Arrays` to get this done but I'm not getting much luck :/

Comment: You use `randomNumber(array:)` and the word equivalent without defining them. Without that detail troubleshooting this is near impossible.  You need to provide a proper minimum reproducible example.

Comment: The functions randomNumber and randomWord can be replaced with array.randomElement().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear how you expect your code to work, or even what you want, but I think this might solve your problem.

```
func genWord( from array: [String]) -> String {
    var position = 0
    var solution = ""
    let indicies = array.indices.shuffled()  //randomises the order the words are used
    
    for index in indicies {
        let word = array[index]
        if position < word.count  {
            let char = word[ word.index(word.startIndex, offsetBy: position, limitedBy: word.endIndex)!]
            solution += String(char)
            position += 1
        }
    }   
    return solution
}
```

Note: if the word does not have enough characters to give you a value at `position` it is discarded and the next one tried.